# How do you convert a scid database into a pgn database?

Tags: database, pgn, scid

So I got a big scid database and ScidvsMac. I would like to convert the complete database into a pgn database. So far I have only found out how to convert single games into pgn, something I'm not keen on doing a million times.

So how do you do this with scid? And if scid doesn't have this functionality, is it possible to maybe do it game by game via command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the `Tools` menu and somewhere down you will find under the option `Export Current Game` the option `Export All Filter Games`. In this sub-menu there is the option to export them as PGN.

Comment: Thanks! I just found out myself ;-) One thing to add maybe: When you open a database the filter is set to the complete database, but if you have done a search you may have to reset it under Search -> Reset Filter to actually convert the complete database.